# How to create a Boolean Function to list objects in a Generic Collection?

Tags: vb.net

After creating a `List(Of T)`, I want to create a`Boolean` function. First, we will ask data to add an object in the list. However, in case this new object has the same "DNI" (String attribute from the class Aspirante), then we cannot include this new Object in the list. Therefore, it should be `True` when we have an Object with the same attribute and `False` when we don´t, so we can add the new object.

Below is the code I did:

```
Public Class Oposicion

        Private datos As New List(Of Aspirante)()
     

        Public Function Alta(ByRef objAspirante As Aspirante) As Boolean


            If datos.Contains(objAspirante.DNI) Then
               

                Return True

            Else

                datos.Add(objAspirante)

                Return False
            End If
        End Function



End Class
```

However it doesn´t work. I have no clue on how to do it. Sorry if I was not clear enough.

Comment: Hi Julen. Your code is visibly not VBA code. VBA and VB.NET have similarity,but are not the same languages.

Comment: For the love of ducks, why "ByRef"?!  That should be "ByVal".  Passing by reference means you could assign a new instance of Aspirante to "objAspirante",  inside your Alta() function, and then whatever variable pointed to the previous instance would point to the new instance, even on the OUTSIDE of your function.  Probably not what you wanted, or needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `List(Of String)` containing the just the DNI property of each object in `datos`. Then see if the DNI of `objAspirante` is contained in `lst`.

```
Public Class Oposicion
    Private datos As New List(Of Aspirante)()

    Public Function Alta(objAspirante As Aspirante) As Boolean
        Dim lst As New List(Of String)
        For Each a As Aspirante In datos
            lst.Add(a.DNI)
        Next
        If lst.Contains(objAspirante.DNI) Then
            Return True
        Else
            datos.Add(objAspirante)
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

End Class
```

If you can change the type of datos, this might be easier.

```
Public Class Oposicion
    Private datos As New Dictionary(Of String, Aspirante)()

    Public Function Alta(objAspirante As Aspirante) As Boolean
        If datos.ContainsKey(objAspirante.DNI) Then
            Return True
        Else
            datos.Add(objAspirante.DNI, objAspirante)
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: If you're creating an additional collection solely for checking for a pre-existing value, why would you use a `List` instead of a `HashSet`?  For that matter, why would you keep it in the add routine (so that you have to build it each time) instead of at the class level?

Comment: @Craig  Actually, I was thinking of a dictionary for datos with the being DNI and the value being Aspirante.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your question directly but it involves a significant amount of code, so it won't work in a comment.

You probably shouldn't be using a `List(Of T)` in the first place. The `HashSet(Of T)` already includes functionality to prevent adding duplicate items, so that may be a better option. If you want to compare objects on a specific property value then you need to first create a comparer based on that:

```vb
Public Class Thing

    Public Property Stuff As String

End Class


Public Class ThingComparer
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Thing)

    Public Overloads Function Equals(x As Thing, y As Thing) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Thing).Equals
        Return x.Stuff.Equals(y.Stuff)
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function GetHashCode(obj As Thing) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Thing).GetHashCode
        Return obj.GetHashCode()
    End Function

End Class
```

You then create a `HashSet(Of T)` that uses that comparer to determine equality:

```vb
Dim things As New HashSet(Of Thing)(New ThingComparer)
```

You can then just add items as you please by calling `Add`. That will either add the new item and return `True` or it will not not add the duplicate item and return `False`:

```vb
Dim variousStuff = {"One", "Two", "One"}

For Each stuff In variousStuff
    Dim something As New Thing With {.Stuff = stuff}

    If things.Add(something) Then
        Console.WriteLine($"'{stuff}' was added successfully.")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine($"'{stuff}' is a duplicate and was not added.")
    End If
Next
```

The potential drawback is that `HasSet(Of T)` does not implement `IList(Of T)`, so you cannot access items by index. It does implement `ICollection(OF T)` though, so it does have a `Count` property and you can enumerate it with a `For Each` loop.

Comment: Thanks looks this solution could help me! Have a nice day!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with your existing `List(Of Aspirante)`, then simply use `.Any()` and pass it a Lambda to determine if one already exists.  It'd look something like this:

```
Public Function Alta(ByVal objAspirante As Aspirante) As Boolean
    If Not datos.Any(Function(x) x.DNI = objAspirante.DNI) Then
        datos.Add(objAspirante)
        Return True ' your description and code did not match for these!
    End If
    Return False ' your description and code did not match for these!
End Function
```

Note my comment on the `Return` lines...your code and description did not match here.